# Mongoose Followers/Friends Relationship Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a query that returns posts from both Friends and Non-Friends, but ensures Friends Posts are at top of list. What I have now only gets posts from Friends:

Schemas

```
var Post = mongoose.Schema({
     name: String,
     user: { type:ObjectId, ref:'User' },
     createdAt: { type:Date, default:Date.now }
});

var User = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String
});

var Relationship = mongoose.Schema({
    from: { type:ObjectId, ref:'User' },
    to:   { type:ObjectId, ref:'User' }
});
```

Query looks like

```
Relationship.find({ from : thisUser },function(err,docs){
     if (err) {console.log(err);}

     var query = Post.find();
     var plucked = _.pluck(docs,'to');

     query.where('user').in( plucked );
     query.sort('-createdAt');
     query.limit(20);
     query.skip( 20 * page);
     query.exec(function(err,posts){
         if (err) {console.log(err);}
         res.send(posts);
     });
});
```

The client will grab say 20 posts on each page. So any suggestions on how I can return all posts, but ensure posts by Friends appear first? For instance, if there are 100 posts that meet the query criteria and 30 of those are from friends, the first page and half of the second will all be friends posts (sorted by createdAt).

If I need to redo the schemas and relationships thats fine as well.

Comment: You will need to split this query into two parts: the first for finding the posts of friends (let's call this list F), the second for finding all posts (let's call this list A). Then you will need to compute (A - F) -- in other words remove all friend's posts form A. Subsequently return the concatenation of (F:(A-F)).

Comment: That makes sense, but would that technique work efficiently if I had say 100,000 posts?

Comment: Well then you would need to limit the amount of posts to be returned in each query to the number you want to display (e.g. 100). Having an appropriate index in place (upon createdAt), this will not be a problem for mongodb.

Comment: I updated my current answer with skip and limit, let's see if I can figure out your answer though

Answer (score -1):

What I would have done is to skip the Relationship model all together (if it is not absolutely essential) and have a friends field in User like this instead:

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    friends: [User],
});
```

Then you're able to query the friends posts like this:

```
Post.find({user: {$in: thisUser.friends}}, function(err, posts) {
    ...
})
```

And append it with non-friends using $nin instead of $in.

Comment: This looks like it would work, however paging and scalability seem like they would still be a problem. There will be lots of relationships and lots of posts. For the time being I removed the relationships all together, but I plan on putting them back in soon. So I am going to leave this question open.

Answer (score -2):

Honestly, the best thing to do is to store the user names with the friendship object. This information is extremely unlikely to change. How many times have you changed your name on Facebook?

Comment: And if it happens once?

Comment: Then simply update the records and use { multi: true }